# How to get action bar title as TextView in AppCompat?

Tags: android

I'm trying this to get title as TextView but it's not working:

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
```

And title is null. How to get title as TextView using AppCompat?

Comment: are you using toolbar ?

Comment: @r7v No, I don't using toolbar.

Comment: @r7v Is there difference beetwen toolbar and action bar?

Comment: whats your usecase ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically when using the Toolbar in my cases, if I am doing something custom with the title, I will just inflate the title view manually, then set its attributes in XML. The point of Toolbar is to prevent things like this from happening, so you can have more control over what your toolbar looks like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_vertical_increment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_vertical_increment"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background">


    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/Red" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in code, you would do something like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
//Get rid of the title drawn by the toolbar automatically
toolbar.setTitle("");
TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
toolbarTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Taken from [Getting ActionBar Title TextView with AppCompat v7 r21](http://www.widecodes.com/CHVVeVWWVV/getting-actionbar-title-textview-with-appcompat-v7-r21.html)

Comment: Is there difference beetwen action bar and toolbar?

Comment: you can find here at [The official blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Comment: Android developers, needed more control over ActionBar, and Toolbar is just for it.
In other words, the ActionBar now became a special kind of Toolbar

Comment: you should also see [Google Design Spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

Answer (score 4):

Brute force seems to be one solution:

```
private void findTextViewTitle() {        
    String title = "title";

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setTitle(title);

    Window window = getWindow();
    View decor = window.getDecorView();

    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    decor.findViewsWithText(views, title, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);

    for (View view : views) {
        Log.d(TAG, "view " + view.toString());
    }

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) decor.findViewById(views.get(0).getId());
    tvTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to get the TextView from the ActionBar. This method ensures that the TextView is selected even if the ActionBar orientation changes. It also allows you to get the icon if you ever want - just check for child instanceof ImageView.

```
//If you just want to set the text
ActionBar actBar = getSupportActionBar();
if(actBar != null) {
    actBar.setTitle(R.string.your_ab_title);
}

//If you want to customize more than the text    
Toolbar ab = findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
if(ab != null){
    for (int i= 0; i < ab.getChildCount(); i++){            
        if(ab.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) {
            TextView title = (TextView) ab.getChildAt(i);

            //You now have the title textView. Do something with it
            title.setText("Your Custom AB Title");
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

im using AppCompatActivity , this works for me

```
val titleId :Int = resources.getIdentifier("title","id",BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID )
        val title :TextView = findViewById(titleId)
```

[image: Layout Inspector]

Comment: I am using `androidX` library and mID = -1 for `TextView` containing the title in the ToolBar.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the help everyone here, here's the implementation i ended up with.

[image: Example Font Set]

```
// USAGE
Toolbar yourToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar);
TextView actionTitle = ActionBarTitle(toolbar);
    actionTitle.setTypeface(font("Snake"));


// IMPLEMENTATION
private TextView ActionBarTitle(Toolbar toolbarForRead)
{
    TextView title = null;
    if (toolbarForRead != null)
    {
        for (int i= 0; i < toolbarForRead.getChildCount(); i++)
        {            
            if (toolbarForRead.getChildAt(i) instanceof 
TextView)
            {
                title = (TextView) 
toolbarForRead.getChildAt(i);
                return title;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
private Typeface font(String fontName)
{
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/"  + fontName + ".ttf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The textView in Toolbar is added by code, so you cannot find it by view id.

#### Solution

With Kotlin, you can find the title textView by this way.

```kotlin
toolbar.forEachIndexed { _, v ->
    if (v is TextView && v.text == "Your title name") {
        v.setOnClickListener {
            // ...
        }
        return@forEachIndexed
    }
}
```